# Visual Studio 2003 Inserting Spaces

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2003

Has anybody else ever had this issue:

Running VS2003 off Server'03 and, out of nowhere one day on my VB Web App, spaces are getting inserted into the HTML section of my .aspx file.  So a simply opening a table gets modified to "<   td>" (YES, spaces included!) and of course fails.

So then.. I correct all the spacing errors, fine.. and suddenly subroutine calls that ran just fine the day before are getting compile errors.

Is it possible that a VS2003 setting could be affecting the file and cause it to automatically edit the file in this way?

Yes, I'm stuck with using the version of VS that's on this particular Server.

Comment: What type of source control do you use?

Comment: At the time, yes I did have a cat, but she is no longer in this world...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2003 was renowned for auto formatting problems in HTML. Do these things and see if it helps:

1) Go to Tools Menu, Options
- Go to Text Editor, then to HTML and make sure any auto formmating is disabled
- Go to Html Designer and make sure default view is source view and also make sure

2) Don't use the HTML designer

3) Double check that you have the latest service pack for VS 2003 installed.

4) (Optional) Get Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Nope, stuck with VS2003.  I completed this project without tearing too much hair out.